# how to detect logic_error exception before runtime?

Tags: c++, exception

c++ standard says that logic_error could detect before runtime 
while runtime_error detect at runtime.

but how is it working? 
My question is how to detect logic_error before runtime.
could you give me some example? thanks for help~!

Comment: a logic error is by definition ["a consequence of faulty logic within the program"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error), hence you could detect the cause in your code, but thats nothing someone else can do for you

Comment: "c++ standard says that logic_error could detect before runtime", could you please quote the relevant part?

Comment: *Where* does it say that [the `logic_error` exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) could be caught before runtime? That's not really how exceptions work. You can *find* logic errors either through the compiler giving you warnings or through the use of static analysis tools, or by simple code review. But there's no way of catching C++ exceptions (no matter what kind of exception) at compile-time.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ standard says this about [`logic_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) (§22.2.2) :

> The class `logic_error` defines the type of objects thrown as exceptions to report errors presumably detectable before the program executes, such as violations of logical preconditions or class invariants.

This does not mean that the exception can be caught at compile time. It means that the *cause* of the exception could be detected through other means (compiler warnings, code analysis, etc.) at compile time.

Comment: so it just says you can detect logie_errors on your eyes or some things.. but runtime_error is hard to find error on your eyes or some things? and both of them not that different much?

Comment: @rebraian : your eyes are indeed good tools to detect logic errors. Runtime errors typically depend on specific runtime conditions. You can still detect them (with your eyes or otherwise) at compile time, as long as you imagine those specific runtime conditions.

Comment: @rebraian : the difference between [`std::logic_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) and [`std::runtime_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) is described in the linked reference pages. Logic errors are due to faulty logic (eg. accessing an array out of bounds), while runtime errors are due to events occurring outside of the scope of the code (eg. arithmetic overflow).

Answer (score 2):

I think your misunderstanding is between what causes the exception to be thrown and the exception itself. There are exceptions that cannot be avoided even in a completely bug-free program, for example ones caused by user input. Then there are other exceptions that are clearly caused by writing logically wrong code. Consider this function:

```
double sqrt(double x); // takes only positive numbers
```

Now if I use this function like this:

```
double y = sqrt(-2);
```

then I made a logic error. I didnt respect the preconditions on the parameter to the function. In such a case it could be the right thing (*)  to do for sqrt to throw a `std::logic_error` (as opposed to a plain `runtime_error`).

```
double sqrt(double x) {
    if (x < 0) throw std::logic_error();
    //....
```

Now when you read somewhere that "logic errors can be detected before runtime" then this most likely refers to the fact that one can read the code and see that calling `sqrt(-2)` is indeed wrong and fix it. However, note that this is unrelated to the actual exception being thrown (which is purely a runtime concept).

So to answer your question literally: You detect logic errors in your code by careful analysis. Pay attention to compiler warnings, ask co-workes for a review, use static analysis tools, etc.

(*) = maybe `logic_error` isnt the perfect thing to throw here, so please take the example with a grain of salt.

Comment: @rebraian please consider to accept one of the answers (not necessarily mine ;)